# database nomenclature for abstracting an instance of a class of data

Tags: mysql, naming-conventions

```
TABLE                   FIELDS
users                   user_id

items                   item_id

item_instance           item_inst_id
                        item_inst_qty
                        user_id
                        item_id
```

The first table has all the users, and the second table has all the items.

The third table records the quantity of a specific item which a user has. It is not recording data about the item itself, but rather the data about the relationship between the item and user.

My question is what is the third type of table generally referred to as? The most accurate abstraction I could think of is "instance," as taken from OOP, because each data record represents an occurrance of a particular class of data, which in this case is the "item" class. Also, "case" was another possiblity.

In database programing, is there a generally accepted term for a table which has records that tie two tables together in this manner? Or is the naming convention usually up to the programmer? If the latter, what is your take?